# How to calculate Annualized tracking error of an Index fund given daily historical data?

Tags: technical-analysis, mutual-fund, tracking-error

Let's say I have Fund A and Benchmark B and the daily data for both, stretching back 5 years.

To find the Annualized Tracking Error (ATE), would this method be correct:
[image]

1. Compute percentage change of A's daily value relative to its previous day's value
2. Compute same for B
3. Compute the difference
   between 1 and 2
4. Do this for all 5 years worth of daily data. Step 3 will look like a column with ~1250 rows of data
5. Compute the standard deviation of this whole column (stdev.s). Per my understanding this would be the Tracking error for the entire 5 years. Let's call it K
6. To find the Annualized tracking error,
   annualize the above i.e.
   Annualized TE= (1+k)^(1/5) - 1

**Questions:**

- My confusion is in the annualizing step. Instead of my formula in step 6, should I be using k * sqrt(250)?
- Let's say the result is 0.000142. Does this mean TE is 0.01%?
- Would I be right in assuming that calculating all this with daily
  data would yield a far more accurate TE than with monthly data?

Comment: Because you are using daily data the annualization formula to use is the second one, the one with $\sqrt{250}$

Comment: Appreciate that, @noob2. What if the result is 0.000142. Does that mean ATE is 0.01%?